# Angular2 nested router outlet into component html

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 2, latest version of the router. In the app.component.html I have a  router-outlet named:

```
<router-outlet name="nameA"></router_outlet>
```

In this outlet, i load a component A. In the .html template of the component A, i have another outlet, where i want lo load the component B:

```
<router-outlet name="nameB"></router_outlet>
```

I use the imperative method to navigate:

```
navigate([{ outlets: { nameA:  ['AComp'] } }]);
navigate([{ outlets: { nameB:  ['BComp'] } }]);
```

This is the router:

```
{ path: "AComp", component: AComp, outlet:"nameA" },
{ path: "BComp", component: BComp, outlet:"nameB" }
```

But when i try to load the B component, i receive "Cannot find the outlet nameB to load 'BComp'. I tried to make BComp a children of AComp in the router, but i can't figured out how.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling B Component? is that after the A Component?

Comment: Yes, after A component; I call BComp through a button in another componentC loaded within A component with <c-comp> tag